# Jquery draggable decide how far I can grab

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to understand jquery draggable interactions, my goal is to be able to move the text only to the right 200px then stop and not to the left from it's normal position, but if it's dragged to the right I should be able to drag it back to the left. Is there a smart and easy way to acheive this? Couldn't find anything in the [documentation](https://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/)?

```js
$("#drag").draggable({
  axis: "x"
});
```

```css
.draggable {
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  padding: 0.5em;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />

<div id="drag" class="draggable ui-widget-content">
  <p>I can be dragged only horizontally</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make this work you can use the `drag` event. You can check the current position is within acceptable horizontal bounds (0-200px given the description in the question) and then disallow anything outside of that using `Math.max()` and `Math.min()`:

```js
$("#drag").draggable({
  axis: "x",
  drag: function(event, ui) {
    ui.position.left = Math.max(0, Math.min(200, ui.position.left));
  }
});
```

```css
.draggable {
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  padding: 0.5em;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<div id="drag" class="draggable ui-widget-content">
  <p>I can be dragged only horizontally</p>
</div>
```

One final thing to note is that the versions of jQuery and jQueryUI in your fiddle are very out of date. You need to update them ASAP, as I've done in the example above.

Comment: No problem, glad to help